# Ember.js Assetion failed due to modification after rendering

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am developing a very simple ember component structure and I keep encountering the same error:

```
Assertion Failed: You modified "pipeline.status" twice on <frontend@model:pipeline-instance::ember497:59636F5284D6CE0009000002> in a single render. It was rendered in "component:pipeline-manager" and modified in "component:pipeline-manager". This was unreliable and slow in Ember 1.x and is no longer supported. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13948 for more details.
```

I have stripped down all the functionality to this very simple code and I keep having the assertion error.

The **pipeline-instance.js** model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  status: DS.belongsTo('status')
});
```

The **pipeline-manager.js** is empty.

The **pipeline-manager.hbs** template:

```
<div class="pipelines--show">
  <div class="row status">
    Current status: {{await pipeline.status.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**package.json**:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "ember-cli": "2.11.1",
  "ember-cli-app-version": "^2.0.0",
  ...
 }
```

It seems that the only way I manage to get rid of the error is by using `ember s --prod`

Comment: What is your ember-data version ?. unfortunately there is known issue for ember-data 2.14.0

Comment: Yes, sorry:     "ember-data": "^2.11.0", I just can't remember what changed, it worked properly a little ago and I had changed nothing, just rebuilt. Perhaps a new version came in an broke it. I will test with fixed version.

Comment: Yes. when you have `^` then it will may update your ember-data ro recent version. So I will ask you to lock ember-data to a specific version like `"ember-data":2.13.0`. remove node_modules and do npm install again. Ember Assertion code will be stripped down for production environment that's the reason you are not getting the error in console, but underlying issue(double render) will be there.

Comment: Yes, yes I am aware of the versioning. I didn't think it would be the ember-data version, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4942) in `ember-data@2.14.0` that is causing this.  You will see the message regarding the failed assertion any time you reference a property of a related model in a template (such as your example from above: `pipeline.status.title`).  Run `npm list ember-data` to confirm you are running `2.14.x`

For the time being, I suggest reverting back to `ember-data@2.13.2` - just specify 2.13.2 in your package.json like this: `"ember-data": "2.13.2"`.  When a new version of `ember-cli`/`ember-data` is released that fixes this issue, you can update `package.json` as part of the normal upgrade process via `ember init`.

There is already a [Pull Request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/5042) for the fix for this issue, so let's hope it gets merged soon so we can upgrade.